# in mongodb is it possible to backup and restore a specific collection in database?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb is it possible to backup and restore a single collection in database?. Recently came across a database which which started as VM1 (primary) and VM2 (secondary) which at some point it time has failed over to VM2 (new primary) and VM1(New Secondary). When I took over the database looked at the collection in a database notices one of the collections in the database VM1 is not there in VM2.

Is there a way I can backup that specific collection in the database delete the collection and then import it to VM2 (New Primary) in the same database?

Comment: Does this help - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/?

Answer (score 0):

To export a specific collection use the below syntax

mongodump --port 27020 
--db test 
--collection restaurants 
--out /mydata/restoredata/

To import to another VM - do the below

mongorestore --port 27017 --db test2 --collection rest2 /mydata/restoredata/test/restaurants.bson --drop

More details here -

https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/restore-single-database/